# Modification Request SQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a table SQL and I fill it from an Excel File. The problem is many fields are repeated. For example:

```
FOURNITURE      MFC       SERIE  
FOURNITURE      MFC       SERIE 
FOURNITURE      MFC       SERIE
```

Here in my table, I find just one line. It jumps up all the rest. However, I need to get all the lines.

My request is:

```
if ($articleid == 'DIEPRESTATION' || $articleid == 'DIEDIVBIEN' ||$articleid =='DIEDIVERS')
{
    if(!($this->_db->query("INSERT INTO `article` (`ID_Article`, `Designiation`, `Ident`, `ID_LRU`) VALUES ('".$articleid."', '".$designation."', '".$ident."', '".$IdLRU."');")))
{   
        if ($LRU != 'new')
        {
          return $this->_db->query(" UPDATE  `FLOOSE`.`article` SET  `ID_LRU` =  
          '".$IdLRU."' WHERE  `article`.`ID_Article` =  '".$articleid."' AND  
            `article`.`Designiation` =  '".$designation."' AND  
             `article`.`Ident` =  '".$ident."' LIMIT 1 ;");
        } 
        else {
                return false;
            }
        } else{
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

I think I have a unique key constraint on two table columns. 
[image: screen sheet of the structure of my table]

How can I change it or take a test to recover all the lines? I delete the unique key constraint ?
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, I don't understand your question. You wrote you need to *get all the lines*. A `SELECT` query should do that for you. But your example code shows `UPDATE` and `INSERT` queries.  Are you trying to `UPDATE` all matching lines in your DBMS?  If so, why does your `UPDATE` query contain the `LIMIT 1` clause?

Comment: Is it failing with a duplicate constraint error? If so, the easiest option is to make ID_Article the primary key (Integer and AutoIncrement).

Comment: My code shows UPDATE and INSERT queries because I have a Join with another table. When it find the LRU is old it take just UPDATE.

Comment: With respect, please find a colleague to help you with the English language to clarify your question.

Comment: I don't make the ID_Article AutoIncrement because her value I recovre it from a Excel File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do have a unique constraint on your columns. And even more, the composite of `ID_Article`, `Designiation` is your **primary key**, which is per definition also unique.

You should

1. remove that primary key: `ALTER TABLE article DROP PRIMARY KEY;`
2. add another field (name it `id` to stick with conventions), and set it as primary key with auto-increment: `ALTER TABLE article ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Comment: The new field I add it in the request also in my code PHP ? If I delete the unique constraint and I run the insert, it will work ?

Comment: I edited my answer. You don't need to remove and re-insert all data, you can also add an auto-incrementing primary key on the existing table.